# A subset $A$ of a manifold $X$ that is a manifold but not a submanifold of $X$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Let $X$ be a manifold and $A$ a subset of $X$. Is it possible for $A$ to be a manifold without being a submanifold of $X$. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: What's your definition of "submanifold"?

Comment: I didn't know there more than one definition of a submanifold..I thought there were only one that defines a submanifold as a subset that is itself a manifold.. Is there another one?

Comment: Rule of thumb: there are **always** several different definitions. (Here and there, all but one may have died out, but remember, people can't even agree on whether $0\in\mathbb{N}$, you can't expect them to agree on more complicated matters.)

Comment: Ok Daniel, I will not forget that :) what about the most common definition that I gave?

Comment: Definitions of submanifold: $S \subset M$ is a $k$-dimensional submanifold of $M$ if every $x\in M$ has a coordinate neighbourhood $U$ with a coordinate chart $\varphi\colon U \to V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (where $n = \dim M$) such that $\varphi(U\cap S) = \{ x \in V : x_{n-k+1} = \dotsc = x_n = 0\}$. Different definition: require such a neighbourhood only for $x\in S$. These two are the most common ones in my experience. The first makes examples of a subset that is not a submanifold but a manifold easy. The second not.

Comment: Could you please give me an example for the first definition. I just want to understand what can go wrong preventing the manifold from being a submanifold.

Comment: In the first definition, any open but not closed subset of $M$ is a manifold, but not a submanifold of $M$, since the boundary points don't have a neighbourhood of the required form. Only apparently less trivial, take $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \lVert x\rVert = 1, x_3 > 0\}$ the points on the unit circle in the $x_3 = 0$ plane lack a neighbourhood of the specified form. In that definition, a submanifold is in particular a closed subspace. In the second definition, these trivial examples are submanifolds, and you need something weird to find an example (see below).

Comment: In the definition of $S$ you mean $x_3=0$ or $x_3>0$? What about the vertex point of the cone is it a submanifold of the cone ?

Comment: I meant $x_3 > 0$ to have an open half-sphere. A single point is always a submanifold (of dimension $0$), provided the ambient space is a manifold.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify a number of things in your question, including what is the manifold category you are working in. Since you did not specify the category, I assume you are working with topological manifolds. In this context, the most common notion of a submanifold is as follows: A subset $A\subset X$ of a topological $n$-manifold $X$ is called a $k$-dimensional submanifold if for every $a\in A$ there exists an open neighborhood $U\subset X$ of $a$ and a homeomorphism $f: U\to R^n$ such that $f$ sends $U\cap A$ homeomorphically to a coordinate subspace $R^k\subset R^n$. A classical example then is the **[Alexander's horned sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere)** $A\subset R^3$, which is a compact subset homeomorphic to the usual 2-dimensional sphere, but $A$ is not a submanifold in $R^3$.

Comment: In this comment http://mathoverflow.net/questions/79431/locally-flat-submanifold @Ryan Budney says: "Then Alexander's Horned Sphere is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$" !!

Comment: @palio: You would have to ask Ryan what definition of a submanifold he was using in his comment. Alexander's sphere is not a submanifold with the definition given above (according to which, submanifolds are required to be "locally flat" or "locally tame").

Comment: @palio: Most likely, Ryan Budney was using the definition that every subset $A$ of a manifold $X$, so that $A$ is a manifold in the subset topology, is a submanifold of $X$. With this definition, your question has the obvious answer. In any case, as Daniel Fischer said in his comments, this is your responsibility to make sure that people reading your question know what the question actually is. This includes stating explicitly what is your notion of a manifold (topological, PL or smooth) and what is your definition of submanifold.

Comment: I work in the topological manifold setting without any further structure. I think yes the topology on $A$ is the subset topology and I think all the definitions use this topology. Please Studious, is the boundary circle of the closed disc a one dimensional submanifold of the disc ?

Comment: @palio: Your explanation is good, but is still not good enough to make a precise question. Even your question about the disk is ambiguous: You are mixing topological manifolds and topological manifolds with boundary. These are different things. In the context of submanifolds of manifolds with boundary, the standard definition is more subtle than the one I was using (I was assuming no boundary). Namely, in the category of mlds with boundary one usually requires an extra condition at the bdry points and with this condition, boundary circle is not a submanifold of the closed disk.

Answer (score 2):

The simple (but somewhat rude !) answer is that the question does not make sense:

A set $A$ is just a set but a manifold $M$ is a set $A=|M|$ **plus** a supplementary structure, consisting of  a topology $\mathcal T$ on $A$ and  a family  of bijections $U\to V$ from open subsets   $U\in \mathcal T$ to open balls $V$ of some $\mathbb R^n$.
Of course the bijections have to satisfy  certain axioms.
So it doesn't make sense to wonder if a naked set without a supplementary structure  "is" a manifold

However the stern answer  above is mellowed by the following remarks:

1) Certain subsets $A\subset X$ of a manifold  have a canonical structure of a manifold as soon as they satisfy certain technical conditions (for example to be the locally  the fiber of a submersion).
By **abuse of language** these sets  are then called submanifolds.
But in reality the submanifold  consists of the set $A$ **plus** a supplementary (but canonical) structure, just like any manifold in the universe.

2) Certain subsets $B\subset X$ of a manifold are not submanifolds in the above technical sense but they are so called topological submanifolds:
This means that, if they are endowed with the **supplementary structure** consisting of the induced topology from $X$, they are locally homeomorphic to an open ball in $\mathbb R^k$.
The simplest example is given by the graph $B\subset \mathbb R^2$ of the real function $f(x)=|x|$: that graph   is a topological submanifold but not a submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$.

**Edit**
To prevent misunderstandings: in this answer (sub)manifold means differentiable (sub)manifold. Thanks to studiosus for alerting me to a potential ambiguity.

Comment: Dear Georger Elencwajg: Just a nitpick: In your example the graph is a submanifold in topological and PL category, but not, of course in the smooth category, which is what you surely had in mind.

Comment: Dear @studiosus, yes:  I say explicitly that the graph is a topological manifold but not a submanifold, which in the context  is supposed to mean  not a differentiable submanifold (cf. the second sentence of the answer). I wrote an Edit making that explicit.Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

If the manifold $A$ has the same dimension as $X$, then the answer is no: $A$ must be a submanifold of $X$. Equivalently: the inclusion $A \to X$ must be open. This is due to the invariance of domain theorem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain